# how to handle .nextAll() or .prevAll() - each element separately?

Tags: jquery

I am searching for something to make me able control separately each element returned by .prevAll() or .nextAll() jQuery methods.

Something like:

```
<div id="home">
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

And something like:

```
$('#home .box').mouseover(function(){

var hovBox = $(this);
var prevAll = hovBox.prevAll();
var nextAll = hovBox.nextAll();

     nextAll.each(function(){

           // ...and do something with each returned element
           // NOT with ALL returned elements, just handle each separately
           // through some other type of selector
     });
});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Just tell your goal why do you want to handle them separately because there might be better solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$.each allows you access the DOM element using `this`:

```
nextAll.each(function(index){
    // ...and do something with each returned element
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', index/5);
});
```

Here's the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2MMGw/1/

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: In my example... Ex: if you hover the 4th box, how can I do something with the first box before that one, second, and third... ?!

Comment: @Gina: what is your actual goal? This answer actually is pretty correct, you can do something with *every* element in those wrapped sets.

Comment: Ok... thanks for your comments... I'll try like suggested, but I think this won't work. Let me try

Comment: @jAndy ... thanks for the demo! :) But when I mean separately (in your demo) it would be something like give all returned elements a different type of opacity! How to handle (if I hover 4) the .box 3,4,1 INDEPENDENTLY ?

Comment: @Gina Could you use the index parameter supplied by .each for this?

Comment: @jncraton ! hura! I'll give it a try! I think you can edit the Answer! I think this might help!

Comment: @jAndy ... too many cases (the .box number can variate)...  The jncraton Ex. looks simpler I think: http://jsfiddle.net/2MMGw/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
nextAll.each(function(index){
   //index=0 will be the first box after that one
   //index=1 will be the 2nd box 
   //index=2 will be the 3nd box 

   alert(index);
});
```

For eg, if you want a specific thing with the second one

```
  nextAll.each(function(index){
     //do something
    if (index==1)
    {
    $(this).hide(); //do specific thing
    }
    alert(index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that somithing that you looking for

```
   nextAll.each(function(i){            
       if(i>0){
          $(this).css('color','#ff000');// will give color all elements after 1st element that you hover
        }

     });
```

Comment: this is not working.... I think. Correct me if I'm wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/jzfFb/3/

Comment: @Sarath, the index should be based on 0. So in your eg, it should be i>1.